# creating consumers to queue in ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am new to manage the ActiveMQ. I have created a "testQueue" from the management console. I want to restrict this queue to a certain user who has valid credentials of username="Producer" and password="password". I saw the documentation and implemented the below inside the conf file.

```
<simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
  <users>
    <authenticationUser username="Producer" password="password"
        groups="users,admins"/>
  </users>
</simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
```

But I am not able to login to the management console using the credentials. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credentials are for broker users. Systems connecting using OpenWire/JMS, AMQP etc. The management console is not affected and has it's own all or nothing account.